# Annualzing the log of daily returns riddle

Tags: volatility, risk, returns, statistics, lognormal

Two popular ways to measure returns are Arithmetic returns and Log returns. Let's define arithmetic (simple period) returns as: P(t) - P(t-1) / P(t-1). Let's define log return as Ln( P(t)/P(t-1) ) or equivalently Ln(1 + arithmetic return).

The log returns have nice properties -- logarithmic returns prevents security prices from becoming negative; we can interpret log returns as continuously compounded returns; they are approximately equal to simple returns at small values; if the security price follows Brownian motion then the log returns are normally distributed; logs convert products into sums. Jorion (2001) has a brief description of the properties and application of the log description (pg. 94): [Jorion 2001](http://books.google.com/books?id=nnblKhI7KP8C&lpg=PA75&pg=PA94#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Let's say a security lost 1% (simple return) today. We would like to annualize this daily return (as it is an input to some risk model whose outputs we would like on an annualized basis). So: Ln(1 -.01) * 251 trading days = -2.52 annualized return. However, a security cannot lose more than 100% of its value. How do we explain this outcome (i.e. what is the right operation such that the lower bound on the log return is > -1)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're forgetting that -2.52 is still in natural logarithm terms. So the correct answer is 2.71828183 raised to the -2.52 power which equals 0.08. Your ending portfolio value is 8% of what it was a year ago.

Comment: Granted that (1 + R)^251 = .08. However, this is not a solution as it side-steps the problem by stating the problem in arithmetic returns. It is general practice to use a continuously compounded return such as Ln(1+R) for regression, to continuously compound interest, price options, etc. My point is that the log form of the return has no economic meaning when a large value of arithmetic return are involved. Even in the seemingly everyday case of annualized daily returns we seem to bump up against this < -1 issue

Comment: Joshua's point was that when you convert to log returns, you also need to convert your bounds to log returns.  A 100% loss corresponds to a log loss of -infinity.  Requiring a lower bound on the log return of -1 is equivalent to requiring a lower bound on the arithmetic return of -63.3%.

Comment: @Frank Fingerman - Thanks, better said than I could.

Comment: @Quant Guy - I had what I think is a similar problem: how do I compare quarterly earnings growth for stocks whose prior quarter's earnings was negative and this quarter is positive (or vice versa). My solution is ln(absolute(current.earnings))*sign(current.earnings) minus ln(absolute(past.earnings))*sign(past.earnings) --- if either quarter's earnings is zero then obviously substitute zero. That might or might not help but food for thought.

Comment: Thanks Joshua -- yes that is a very similar problem and creative solution. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

To get the final value, just get $e^{rt}=e^{-0.01 \cdot 252}=8.04 \%$.